# DatePickerDialog date's outside selected date on 5.0

Tags: android, datetime, datepicker, showdialog

On android 5.0, date's outside DatePickerDialog's minDate and maxDate, despite being grey, are still selectable.

[image]

minDate - 16-03-2016 
and
maxDate - 23-03-2016

but still we can select other date like - 08-03-2016

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: only select date between min and max date..